# Array Splitting into K sub-arrays

Tags: arrays

[image]

Split an array into K sub-non zero arrays such that sum of start and end numbers of each sub array is maximum/minimum.

Example:

A=[1,3,5,1] K=2 then for maximum the output is [1,3] and [5,1] because (1+3)+(5+1)=10 and for minimum the output is [1] and[3,5,1] because (1+1)+(3+1)=6{if one item then count it twice as start and end}

Example 2:

A=[1,4,2,5,2] K=3 then for maximum the output is [1,4,2][5][2] because (1+2)+(5+5)+(2+2)=17 and for minimum the output is [1][4][2,5,2] because(1+1)+(4+4)+(2+2)=14

Update-Question image is added for more clarity.

Comment: You've somehow forgotten to write the actual question, and all the details related to it?

Comment: Hello @JamesZ thanks for correcting. However, I saw the statement again. All related details are mentioned in the questions.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If not, then you're in the wrong place. If it is, then it definitely does not have all the details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JamesZ Hello. Please see the image attached. I hope this gives clarity on the question which was not earlier

Comment: No, it definitely does not give clarity. I at least still have no idea what you're asking or is this even programming related.